# Android - Fragment from ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

At the moment I have a activity with a viewpager which inflates a listfragment.
When a user click on a item in the listview I would like to inflate a new fragment.

Test.java

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        final Toolbar toolbar;
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.n_Viewpager);
        this.addPages(vp);

    }

    //ADD ALL PAGES
    private void addPages(ViewPager pager) {
        MyFragPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addPage(new TestFragment());

        //SET ADAPTER TO PAGER
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

layout.activity_test

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="tutorial.com.ScratchGolfer.Test">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/appbarr"
            >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                layout="@layout/app_bar" />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/n_Viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appbarr"
                app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
                />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

TestFragment.java

```
public class TestFragment extends ListFragment {

    //Setting the name of each event
    String[] options = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    //Inflating the view with the fragment
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.listitem, R.id.textview, options);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    }


    //Click events
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos, long l) {
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent0 = new Intent(v.getContext(), NewActivity.class);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent0);
                        break;
                    case 1:

                        break;

                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have managed to open a activity when I click a item in the listview, but I would like to inflate the current activity with a new fragment depending on what item is clicked in the listview

Comment: Where do you want to replace the fragment? inside the `ViewPager`?

Comment: yes, inside the `ViewPager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the best and shortest solution, but I found it more understandable.
You can create a `Fragment` as container and add it to your `ViewPager`. Then replace fragments inside it.

fragment_container.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/fragment_container_root_view">
</LinearLayout>
```

ContainerFragment.Java

```
public class ContainerFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container, container, false);
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_root_view, new TestFragment()).commit();
        return view;
    }
}
```

In you activity:

```
private void addPages(ViewPager pager) {
    MyFragPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addPage(new ContainerFragment());

    //SET ADAPTER TO PAGER
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

In your `TestFragment`:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos, long l) {
            switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                    getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_root_view, new SecondFragment()).addToBackStack("").commit();

                    break;
                case 1:

                    break;

            }

        }
    });
```

I didn't test this code to see if it has error or not, but with some changes, You can achieve to what you want.

Comment: Ok wait you lost me there. My fragment container is `activity_test` it holds a ViewHolder, look at my code above. What is the `fragment_container.xml` you refer to? I also get a error at `ContainerFragment.java` at `new TestFragment()).commit(); `(wrong second argument type). Can you please edit your code so it resembles mine. My main activity is `Test.java ` my main activity is `activity_test.xml `(this holds the viewholder)

Comment: @H.Brooks Ok... look... You have a `Activity` with a `ViewPager` in it. You want to show a `ListFragment` in `ViewPager` and when user clicked on an item, you want to replace another fragment in `ViewPage`... Is that right?

Comment: Now instead of adding `TestFragment` in `ViewPager`, Add `ContainerFragment` in it, then add your `TestFragment` in `ContainerFragment`. now when user clicks on any item, you can replace `SecondFragment` with `TestFragment` in `ContainerFragment`.

Comment: Ok.. I understand.. but I have some errors trying to accomplish this. I get a error in `ContainerFragment` -- `getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_root_view, new TestFragment()).commit();` -- `wrong 2nd argument type` at `new TestFragment `

Comment: @H.Brooks Check your `ListView`extended from `support-v4` package.

Comment: @H.Brooks sorry...I meant `ListFragment`...  Check you extended `TestFragment` from `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`

Comment: @H.Brooks Also extends `ContainerFragment` from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`...

Comment: I GOT IT WORKING! Just one more thing if you don't mind, how can I return back from that fragment without closing the activity?

Comment: @H.Brooks It doesn't return back now? did you use `.addToBackStack("")` in                     `getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_root_view, new SecondFragment()).addToBackStack("").commit();` line
?